# Text on horizontal accordion with height auto

Tags: jquery, css, height, accordion

When I close an accordion, the text inside it is moved at the bottom while the accordion is closing and the height increases.

See it here http://jsfiddle.net/D2HJZ/1/

Accordion HTML:

```
<div id="accordion1">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <div class="accordionSlider">
                <span>text etc...</span>
            </div>
        </dt>
    </dl>
</div>
```

I Changed the height to auto in [awsAccordion](https://github.com/anotherwebstorm/awsAccordion) plugin:

```
//Set attrs for each li and div inside Horizontal       
for (i = 0; i < $(headLis).parent().find('dt').length; i++) {
    $(headLis).parent().find('dt').eq(i).css({
            'width': settings.cssAttrsHor.liWidth + 'px',
            'min-height':'100px',
            'height': 'auto'
        }).find('div.accordionSlider:first').css({
            'left': settings.cssAttrsHor.liWidth + 'px',
            'width': methods.calcDivWidthHor() + 'px',
            'min-height':'100px',
            'height': 'auto'
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know how to solve this issue, so is there any solution?
Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use `Max-height` or fixed `height` for it, and `overflow:hidden;` :

```
 for (i = 0; i < $(headLis).parent().find('dt').length; i++) {

              $(headLis).parent().find('dt').eq(i).css({
                'width': settings.cssAttrsHor.liWidth + 'px',
                'min-height':'100px',

                'max-height':'100px',

                'overflow':'hidden',
                'height': settings.cssAttrsHor.liHeight 

              }).find('div.accordionSlider:first').css({
                'left': settings.cssAttrsHor.liWidth + 'px',
                'width': methods.calcDivWidthHor() + 'px',
                'min-height':'100px',
                'height': settings.cssAttrsHor.liHeight 
              });

            }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ImadBakir! but there are accordions that have many contents. If i get a fixed height the accordion with many contents will not be displayed.